# Qt's installer file gives "... is malicious, and Chrome has blocked it" message in Chrome

Tags: qt, google-chrome

I downloaded Qt from the qt site:

http://qt-project.org/downloads

And upon downloading, I get a message from Chrome that "qt-opensource-win....exe is malicious, and Chrome has blocked it." This was the default link on the page for me, which was:

```
Qt Online Installer for Windows (9 MB) (Info)
```

I also tried downloading:

```
Qt 5.2.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 556 MB) (Info)
```

However, after finishing downloading it gives the same error.

Is this something I should be concerned about? I don't remember getting this error any of the other times I've downloaded Qt.

Comment: That sounds like something to report to Qt project. Probably some virus detection heuristic going bonkers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Chrome's malicious-ness sensing skills.

Comment: This is an Issue on the Chrome side, it is saying it with several other trusted .exe's, with current latest version (50.0.x) it is still possible to get the file entering the downloads tab and clicking "recover malicious file"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I downloaded a different variant of the latest qt opensource installer (qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw48_opengl-5.2.1.exe) and got the same response from Chrome. Following the info link I got the sha-1 and md5 checksums and compared them to what I had downloaded and it was a match. The file is also signed by Digia. Kaspersky also scanned it and came up clean.

It would be great if Chrome had more information on why it thinks these downloads are malware. It could also be related to the mirror site I used being blacklisted. Apparently Chrome uses a few different criteria including the server you downloaded from.

Comment: Well, this does provide some ways to check, which is useful. Check the `sha-1` and `md5` checksums, check its certificate, and check with virus scan. Another is to check an online virus scan like [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) or [VirusScan](http://www.virscan.org/). Still, sometimes Chrome gives this error and once it did not, so something is weird.

Comment: The OP's question is quite valid: _Is this something I should be concerned about?_ The answer is yes, you should be concerned but there are some steps you can take to avoid what sounds like it could be a potential disaster (i.e. Chrome's confirmation prompt is "OK, hurt me plenty!")

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem as well, today (August the 29th, with Chrome 36.0.1985.143 (Official Build 287914) m on Windows 7 fully updated no problems otherwise, trying to download WindowsX64 QT installer).

This is absolutely unacceptable. If QT, a trusted provided, is being denied, then what else is being consigned to the 'maliciousness,' bin? Is this a liability issue (my first guess, though I find it hard to imagine Google being held liable for all Chrome downloads...)

My solution? Download the files with Firefox. I know that's not a satisfactory solution (and a really obvious one). WTH should anyone need more than one browser? But it's the best I can offer. Lo siento.

P.S. This seems to come down to the QT installer holding an EXE within it. As anyone who has tried to send an EXE over Gmail knows, Google does not like EXEs. Upon reflection, this makes a certain level of sense. If, for example, Chrome blocks all EXEs (and if they didn't, they be open to legal challenge if anyone's PC got virusruined).

If Google were to offer certain exemptions, and, lets say, any single exemption proves viral, then Google would potentially be EVEN MORE LIABLE.

At this point, I'm not even upset. Google is between a rock and a hard place, as far as I can figure, and simply don't have a good option out. They could allow all exes, but that would be dangerous. They could curate a whitelist of accepted exes, which would not just be burdensome to Google's financial bottom line, but would also likely be eternally insufficient.

Forcing the burden of prooving EXE acceptablility unto the users at first seems like a bad idea. But, with the legal and fiduciary realities, Google has no other real choice..

At the end of the day, use (PICK_AN_ALTERNATIVE_BROWSER). I know that's not satisfying. But then again, we're not at the end of history, when everything is just. So let's deal.